# trouble using lambda in python

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to write a lambda where it takes the minutes and divides it by a range, then prints out the result.
I tried

```
       list((lambda minutes: minutes / range),range(Numbe+1,1))
```

but list only takes one argument, any ideas?  Minutes and Number the user supplies

I figured it out using

```
        List=[]
        List=range(1, Number+1)
        List.reverse()
        print(List)
        for number in List:
            print ( minutes/ number)
```

I know that the code look very novice and would appreciate any tips to get is to look better

Comment: This is just a style issue, but you've fallen into the same trap as many beginners. Describe your problem, don't ask how to do what you've decided is the solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to use a lambda? Here is a list comprehension which most people seem to find easier to read

```
[float(minutes)/number for minutes in range(1,number+1)]
```

The equivalent using a lambda function is

```
 map(lambda minutes: float(minutes)/number, range(1,number+1))
```

And a shorter way to write that is

```
map(float(number).__rdiv__, range(1,number+1))
```

The `float` function is needed here (unless you are using Python3) because otherwise an integer division is done

Comment: Instead of using the float function, op can also set "from _ _future_ _ import division".

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `map` built-in function, which acts upon individual elements of the container passed to it as the second argument and returns the result which is a list. The first argument is many a times a lambda which takes the argument and acts upon it. In your case, the minutes and number.

```
map(lambda number:number/rangeval,range(1,rangeval))
```